# How to filter array by comparing two arrays of objects with different elements in their objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

How to filter array by comparing two arrays of objects with different elements in their objects?
I have:

```
arr1 =[{ x: 1, y: 2, z:3 }, { x: 2, y: 1, z:4 }];

arr2 = [{ x: 1, y: 2, a:5 }, { x: 2, y: 3, a:4 }];
```

I want to compare x and y values from both arrays and return the not macthing object from first array, in the above example return `[{ x: 2, y: 1, z:4 }]`
I tried to use `_.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, _.isEqual);` but obviously for this the arrays should have similar objects which is not my case.

Comment: I don't understand the mathematical logic that returned `[{ x: 2, y: 1, z:4 }]` though. Isn't `z: 3` different too?

Comment: @andrewL, I just want to return the whole object which fails to match the two elements x and y

Comment: But the first item in the returned array `x:2` has a matching element in both arrays.

Comment: Both x and y have to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to the right answer.
The `_.differenceWith` function from lodash has three arguments, the array to inspect, the values to exclude and the third argument is a comparator which determines which values you need. In your case, using `_.isEqual` is looking for exactly the same object (which as far as I understood is not your desired behavior).

If you only care about having same `x` and `y` values, try using your custom comparator instead of the `_.isEqual` function from lodash.

It would look something like this:

```
const arr1 = [{ x: 1, y: 2, z:3 }, { x: 2, y: 1, z:4 }];    
const arr2 = [{ x: 1, y: 2, a:5 }, { x: 2, y: 3, a:4 }];

// this is your custom comparator which is called with each value from the two arrays
// I gave descriptive names to the arguments so that it is more clear
const customComparator = (valueFromFirstArray, valueFromSecondArray) =>
  valueFromFirstArray.x === valueFromSecondArray.x
  && valueFromFirstArray.y === valueFromSecondArray.y;

const result = _.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, customComparator);

console.log(result);
// will print [{x: 2, y: 1, z: 4}]
```

Or if you are not familiar with arrow functions, the custom comparator can be declared like this:

```
function customComparator(valueFromFirstArray, valueFromSecondArray) {
  return valueFromFirstArray.x === valueFromSecondArray.x
    && valueFromFirstArray.y === valueFromSecondArray.y
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pg1s9nky/1/) where you can mingle around with the custom comparator if you'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
arr1 =[{ x: 1, y: 2, z:3 }, { x: 2, y: 1, z:4 }];
arr2 = [{ x: 1, y: 2, a:5 }, { x: 2, y: 3, a:4 }];


let notMatched = arr2.filter(function (item, index) {
  return !(item.x === arr1[index].x && item.y == arr1[index].y);
});
console.log(notMatched);
```

Comment: Hi Flash, thanks. But the only problem is the array lengths are not equal hence this will fail and array lengths of both arrays is not fixed and can vary.