# How to compare two arrays with objects to filter the ones that are similar (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays

### Problem

Given the following two arrays:

```js
const myArr1 = [
 { locationPath: 'R0', locationOnGrid: { x: '0', y: '0' } }, // same as second in myArr2
 { locationPath: 'U5', locationOnGrid: { x: '1', y: '0' } },
 { locationPath: 'L3', locationOnGrid: { x: '3', y: '7' } } // same as second in myArr2
]

const myArr2 = [
 { locationPath: 'D0', locationOnGrid: { x: '0', y: '0' } }, // same as second in myArr1
 { locationPath: 'L5', locationOnGrid: { x: '3', y: '7' } }, // same as third in myArr1
 { locationPath: 'L7', locationOnGrid: { x: '0', y: '1' } },
 { locationPath: 'R2', locationOnGrid: { x: '2', y: '2' } }
]

// Do something to 'filter' out the objects that are similar.
```

### Result

Then what I would like to also be able to do after the comparison has been made, is to filter out a certain result:

```js
// Result of the 'filter' function
const found = [
  { locationPath: 'R0', locationOnGrid: { x: '0', y: '0' } },
  { locationPath: 'L5', locationOnGrid: { x: '3', y: '7' } }
];

// and want to do something like the following on the found array:
const startingPoint = ({locationOnGrid}) => {
    return JSON.stringify(locationOnGrid) !== JSON.stringify({ x: '0', y: '0' });
};
const filteredFound = found.filter(startingPoint);
console.log(filteredFound);

// output:
// Array(1)
// 0: {locationPath: "L5", locationOnGrid: {…}}
```

### What I've tried so far:

There are some Stackoverflow questions that relate to the comparison between two Arrays. For example the question [Simplest code for array intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript) and [How to filter array by comparing two elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535254/how-to-filter-array-by-comparing-two-arrays-of-objects-with-different-elements-i) comes really close.

```
// does not work
const found = myArr2.filter((item, index) => {
  return
  (
    item.locationOnGrid.x === myArr1[index].locationOnGrid.x &&
    item.locationOnGrid.y === myArr1[index].locationOnGrid.y
  );
});
console.log(found);
```

Also two arrays don't always necessarily have the same amount of objects. In the example myArr2 has 1 more object. So this works. But for another scenario it could very well be that myArr1 has more objects than myArr2.

Comment: why `'L5'` and not `'L3'`?

Comment: Those are generated. So those don't have to be equal.

Comment: @Remi in the output, first object is taken from array 1 and second object is taken from second array, why it is not taken from first array. that is what Nina is asking

Comment: @Remi Why does the `found` array contain `[R0, L5]` and not `[R0, L3]` or `[D0, L5]`?

Comment: @nickzoum only the ones that have x and y similar should go into the 'found' array.

Comment: @Remi `R0` and `D0` have the same coordinates, `L3` and `L5` have the same coordinates. why is the result `[R0, L5]` and not `[R0, L3]` or `[D0, L5]`?

Comment: @nina-scholz (&Kenny) That was my attempt to compare a value of myArr1 to myArr2.

Comment: Ah I see now. Good point on the coordinates. I need to think about it for a minute what is the desired outcome. I'll adjust the question with this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with normalised key/value pairs, ordered by the key and create a [JSON](https://json.org/).

Then filter the first array and get the common `locationOnGrid` objects.

```js
const
    stringified = o => JSON.stringify(Object.entries(o).sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))),
    array1 = [{ locationPath: 'R0', locationOnGrid: { x: '0', y: '0' } }, { locationPath: 'U5', locationOnGrid: { x: '1', y: '0' } }, { locationPath: 'L3', locationOnGrid: { x: '3', y: '7' } }],
    array2 = [{ locationPath: 'D0', locationOnGrid: { x: '0', y: '0' } }, { locationPath: 'L5', locationOnGrid: { x: '3', y: '7' } }, { locationPath: 'L7', locationOnGrid: { x: '0', y: '1' } }, { locationPath: 'R2', locationOnGrid: { x: '2', y: '2' } }],
    set2 = new Set(array2.map(({ locationOnGrid }) => stringified(locationOnGrid))),
    common = array1.filter(({ locationOnGrid }) => set2.has(stringified(locationOnGrid)));

console.log(common);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Brilliant. Regarding your earlier question, why 'L5' and not 'L3'. In this answer you get L3. If you'd were to switch the two arrays (`array1.map(...` and `array2.filter`) you'd get 'L3' instead of 'L5'. Great!